# Apple Music API get history between Date range

Tags: apple-music, apple-musickit

I would like to get a history of the user's recently played resources. However, I do not want to get the full history but the **history between a specific date range**.

**Example**:

Max has been listening to Apple Music for 5 years now. I would now like to get a list of all the songs he listened to between 1. January 2016 and 31 December 2016.

I haven't found anything about that in Apple's API Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/get_recently_played_resources).

**Does anybody know a workaround to accomplish something as mentioned in the above example? Any help would be greatly appreciated!**